# React replace comma with a new line

Tags: reactjs

How to I replace the comma with a new line?

Want to be like this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJuEk.png)

My code

```
<p className='containerProductDetailsPOne' style={{ overflow:"hidden",overflowY:"scroll" }}>
    {location.state.product.productSpec}
</p>
```

I tried

```
{location.state.product.productSpec.replace(/,/g, '<br>')}
```

and

```
{location.state.product.productSpec.replace(/,/g, '\n')}
```

but does not work

Comment: what this `location.state.product.productSpec` line returning? is this coming from api? are you using any map function before printing the `p` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using replace is not possible to achieve what you want because react just renders the content, not the HTML or neither the HTML tags.

An alternative approach to solve this problem is to split the text using the comma separator as a parameter and display every single content of the resulting array like this:

```
let text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply, dummy text of the printing"
return (
     <div>
         {text.split(",").map((substring, idx)=> {
           return (
               <div key={idx}>
                 <span>{substring}</span>
                 <br />
               </div>
         }
     </div>
```

You can check my example on my code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ritchie-y9j9j2?file=/src/App.js:796-911

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code snippet

```
import React from "react";

class ProductSpec extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
    }


   render()
   {
    let productSpec='Product 1, Product 2, Product 3'
    return(productSpec.split(",").map(p=><p key={p}>{p}</p>));
   }
}

ProductSpec.displayName='ProductSpec'
export default ProductSpec;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let text = "Lorem Ipsum, Is simply, dummy text, of the printing"
return (

 <div>
     {text.split(",").map((substring, index)=> {
       return (
           <div key={index}>
             <span>{substring}</span>
           </div>
     }
 </div>
```